# How to display PyGame framebuffer using systemd service?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi3, systemd

I have created an ambilight clone as a personal learning project. It uses USB webcam to capture required RGB data from TV; it is currently fully functional. My problem is that my RasPi is currently headless and I would like to be able to show stuff on HDMI output; e.g. fill the screen with RGB(0,255,0) which is used for finding the TV screen from the webcam image.

Currently, I am using a class called Hdmi. It uses PyGame surfarray which allows to show NumPy arrays on framebuffer. This works just fine when running the code using "sudo $(which python) webcambilight.py". But when using system, apparently there is no surface. It doesn't give any errors; it just stops running. If I remove the Hdmi class, everything works.

This narrows the problem down to this piece of code:

```
os.putenv('SDL_FBDEV', '/dev/fb0')
os.putenv('SDL_VIDEODRIVER', 'fbcon')
pygame.display.init()
```

I am not very experienced with Linux, but my understanding is that there is no fb0 when running from systemd? I know that services are usually for things that run in the *background*. But this is a special case. I want to launch the service automatically when the device is turned on. Ideally I would never have to log into the device using SSH.

Based on another question/answer on StackOverflow, I've tried this code in .service file.

```
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
```

This didn't help, which I think is because I have no display. Fb0 and fbcon are not really on display=:0, right?

My .service file's contents are currently:

```
[Unit]
Description=Webcambilight
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/webcambilight
ExecStart=/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3cv4/bin/python -u webcambilight.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

NOTE! This works just fine when Hdmi is not on use. But I would love to use it. Now, if I accidentally move my webcam or my TV, I will have to either open YouTube using TV and play a video of greenscreen and then press calibration button on my raspberry (which is a GPIO push button).

What I would want to do is change input to HDMI 4, which is connected to RasPi. Then, by pressing the GPIO calibration button, my Hdmi class would fill the whole 1920x1080 framebuffer with (0,255,0).

Sooo.. any ideas on accessing framebuffer (/dev/fb0?) while running the systemd service?

The full code of Hdmi class is at: https://github.com/sourander/webcambilight/blob/master/wambilight/hdmi.py

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, this fixes it. The systemd is sending hangup signal for reasons beyond my Linux-knowledge.

```
import signal
def handler(signum, frame):
    pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
```